# Selecting strings as variables by their indicators from a file

Tags: python

I have a text file in this format:

```
<pattern>
<line>*string1*"string2" other stuff</line>
<line>random words *string3* random words</line>
</pattern>
```

I want to get the strings between `*` and `"` as different variables by reading the text file. I think it should start like that but I'm not sure which approach should I take for `else` condition

```
def read_pattern():
    patterns = open('a.txt')
    for line in patterns:
        if line == "<pattern>":
            pass
        elif line == "</pattern>":
            break
        else:
```

Addition: There will be more than 50 element which starts with `<pattern>` and ends with `</pattern>` I need to select one of them and read the strings between `<line></line>`tags line by line. For example I have this file:

```
<pattern>
    <line>*mike*"purple" other stuff</line>
    <line>random words *rob* random words</line>
</pattern>
<pattern>
    <line>*tony*"red" other stuff</line>
    <line>random words *mark* random words</line>
</pattern>
```

Let's say I have two variables in my python code `name` and `color` and I choose the second pattern to process. I will read first line first. My variables should be:

```
name=tony
color=red
```

I will use these variables then it comes to second line. My variables should be

```
name=mark
color=(doesn't matter I won't use it)
```

Comment: So `name` is always present but `color` not on every `<line>` ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using an HTML Parser like [BeautifulSoup.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

with open('a.txt') as f:
    soup = BS(f, 'xml')
    print(re.findall(r'(?<=\*).+(?=\*)|(?<=").+(?=")', soup.get_text()))
```

Which yields:

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

If you have a list of patterns you can create your regex dynamically.

Demo:

```
In [35]: import re

In [36]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [37]: patterns = ['*', '"']

In [38]: pat = re.compile('|'.join(['(?<={pat}).+(?={pat})'.format(pat=re.escape(pat)) for pat in patterns]))

In [39]: with open('a.txt') as f:
   ....:     soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')
   ....:     print(pat.findall(soup.get_text()))
   ....:     
['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way there will be more than one patterns. I will select a pattern and I will read it's strings line by line.  Can you update the code for this is it possible?